# Edit a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I can't seem to find any information on what should be a simple issue. I have a table which contains a series of cells. When you tap on the cell it shows the information of that object in detail. I know it is possible to have a button which places all of the data on the screen in EDIT mode. Any tutorials or advice as how to do this (properly/ with best practices)?

Just to be clear this is for iPhone/ Objective-C/ Cocoa.

Thanks,

**EDIT 1**

Sorry. I know how to put the button there. But how do make the labels editable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have editable labels. However, you can replace the label with a textfield when the button is pressed, and then update the label once finished.

One way to do this is the following. Create a textfield in the same location as the label and initially set `textField.hidden = YES;`. Then implement something along these lines:

```
-(IBAction)editMyCell:(id)sender {
  textField.text = cellLabel.text;
  cellLabel.hidden = YES;
  textField.hidden = NO;
  [textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

and when the editing has finished, restore with

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
  cellLabel.text = textField.text;
  textField.hidden = YES;
  cellLabel.hidden = NO;
  [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

You'll probably want to tweak this idea a bit for your situation, but it's probably the simplest thing to implement that achieves what you're after.

Comment: This seems like a good route to take. Any suggestion on the best way to do that :)

Comment: You can create a textfield the same size and location as the label. Then set it to HIDDEN until editing, at which time you set the label to HIDDEN, then back again. Just be sure to sync the text of the TF to that of the label when editing begins, and conversely when it ends.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing two states:

1. Putting the tableView into editing mode - this is for deleting, or moving cells around in the table, regardless of the cell content.  This is controlled by the UITableView.editing property.
   and
2. Putting the tableViewCell into some sort of editing state.  There is no official editing state for the cell (i.e. there is no single flag to set to make all UILabels in a cell into editable textFields.)  You need to implement all of this logic yourself.  If you're using .xibs, a good practice here is to have a different .xib for your cell's editing mode.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the base sdk associated with editing a UIViewController. Normally that kind of logic is defined by the programmer.  But I could see someone writing a function that turns all of your UILabels in your UIView into UITextViews so the user can edit the text.

There might be sample code out there but this seems like custom code to me.